# How can I execute statements in parallel, if I can't extend Thread (since I'm already extending another class)?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Sample extends Panel {

  // Constructor
  public Sample() throws IOException {

     /* JobOne and JobTwo need to be implemented using Thread at same time */

     JobOne{
       //statements
     }

     JobTwo{
       //statements
     }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     new Sample();
  }
}
```

How to perform this, if need these things to be implemented inside the constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't extend Thread, implement java.lang.Runnable. That way you can extend from another class.

You can run it in its own thread like:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(myRunnable).start();
```

Also this way the Runnable isn't locked into being run as an individual thread, it can be handed to an Executor.

See [this article on safe construction techniques](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html) for why you shouldn't start a thread from a constructor.

Comment: That is fine. but will be alright to do this inside a constructor ?

Comment: @aneal: You mean declare the runnable inside a constructor? or are you talking about what goes in the constructor of the thing that implements Runnable?

Comment: @aneal: shouldn't be a problem. but try posting what you want to do in the question so i have a better idea what you want.

Comment: @aneal I don't remember where I read it, but it's considered bad practice to start threads from a constructor.  You can build your Runnable's in the constructor, but then you should have a method `public void start() {thread1.start(); thread2.start();}` that you call after the constructor.  It's bad because you'll probably pass the object you are in the middle of constructing to the Runnable, but the object might not have finished building itself and you'll get some bugs.

Comment: @toto2: that i know. But in my case, i have to start threads inside a constructor. there are option but abit complicated. So, i am just trying to test a easy way.

Comment: @aneal I don't quite understand what you want.

Comment: Thank you guys.The problem is solved with answer provided by Nathan. Thanks again. I just shifted the Jobs from the constructor to a different functions.

Comment: @aneal: with Runnable you should be able to separate creating the Runnables from starting the threads, as toto2 says. maybe that helps? otherwise i don't know either.